# setting fullpath in controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

i have developed a spring application. all requests are dispatching to controllers (i have 2 controllers in my app) so web.xml is like below

in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

aaa controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/aaa")
```

bbb controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/bbb")
```

but now i need to add some jsp pages into my project since the "/*" in web.xml my jsp pages are not found. so i have change the servlet-mapping like below;

in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <url-pattern>/aaa/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/bbb/*</url-pattern>
```

aaa controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
```

bbb controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
```

but i do not want to use this approach since i can access xxx servlet in aaa controler like /bbb/xxx.

so is there any alternative solution, for example can i set full path in controller or anything?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass jsp through the server as well.
You can map it as html extension

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In example-servlet.xml just add the following jsp resolver

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
      <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

and then use ModelAndView Object in your controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/aaa")
public class aaaController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/aaa.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("aaa");
        return mv;
    }
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/bbb")
public class aaaController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/bbb.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("bbb");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

In that case first controller will return /aaa.jsp as you your model andView when you hit /aaa/aaa.html

and second controller will return /bbb.jsp as you your model and View when you hit /bbb/bbb.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/aaa")


 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value="/login")
 public String getLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {  
   model.addAttribute("username", "test");
   return "login";
  }
 }


ERROR---
[PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestServer/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp]


i think i am misunderstood, my problem is that without changing any url in my application adding some jsp pages. 

bwt i can not change the uri since it is already used. uri must be .../TestServer/aaa/login